# NativeScript : Sample groceries sample icon issue

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I am super new to android app dev and was trying out this sample sample-groceries.

I keep getting this error while trying to build the app that 
AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with
value '@drawable/icon'). (using the default android manifest) that came with the download

I checked the apps/App_resources/Android folder and the icon.png is there but is still not loading when i try to build and run it using

tns run android --emulator (emulator starts but no app gets loaded)

will appreciate any help!!

I am using VS Code and android emulator

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/issues/195

Comment: Which branch of sample-Groceries you are trying to start (angular-start or master). Are youfollowing this tutorial here http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1.html ?

Comment: i am using angular-start and yes that is document i followed to set it up